# move just dragged node and its edges in d3 directed graph

Tags: d3.js

I have a d3 directed graph.

right now all the nodes/links are moving when I dragged just one node.

Is there a way to drag just one node with its relevant links in d3 directed graph with causing the entire graph elements to move?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to deactivate force graph functionality on drag.

I think the best way is to stop the simulation on dragstart then instead of changing `fx` `fy` on drag, just update your node and link(s) positions.

```
    .call(d3.drag()  
        .on("start", () => {simulation.stop()})
        .on("drag",function(d){
           // update node/link position
        })
     );
```

Then you can update your simulation node `x` and `y` and restart it later.

Comment: not exactly. I just want the ONE node would be dragged and not effecting the other nodes and edges

Comment: "not effecting the other nodes and edges" = stop the simulation

Comment: like so : https://observablehq.com/d/3a6e3cb85a7c8bce